# Can i stop StreamReader from reading the sub-directories?

Tags: c#

Process gets to the server and directory. How do I get the process to stop reading the entire directory of files used in the path that was passed in?

```
Dts.Events.FireInformation(0, "Attempting to get file: ", ftpFilePath, "", 0, ref False);

        Uri serverUri = new Uri(ftpFilePath);
        FtpWebRequest request;
        FtpWebResponse resp;

            string fileName = "";
            Dts.Variables["User::v_File_Exists"].Value = false;
            Dts.Variables["User::v_Remote_Path"].Value = fileName;
```

Check for the file process is looking for

```
        //Check if file exists on server
        try
        {
            Dts.Events.FireInformation(0, "Try ", ftpFilePath, "", 0, ref False);
            // Get the object used to communicate with the server.
            request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(serverUri);
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;

            FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            //int time = 0;
            Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
```

Would like at this point to stop reading any sub directories after the file is found or not

```
            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
            {
                fileName = reader.ReadLine();
                Dts.Events.FireInformation(0, "Beginning of While loop ", fileName, "", 0, ref 
False);
                int index = fileName.IndexOf(".BO");
                //string subFolder = fileName.Substring(1, 5);
               // Dts.Events.FireInformation(0, "subfolder ", subFolder, "", 0, ref False);
                if (index != -1)
                {
                    //if (subfolderindicator != "/")

                        Dts.Events.FireInformation(0, "Valid File ", fileName, "", 0, ref False);
                        int time = 0;
                        string store = fileName.Substring(index - 8, 4);
                        Dts.Events.FireInformation(0, "store ", store, "", 0, ref False);
```

Check the filename

```
if (store == Dts.Variables["User::v_Store_Number"].Value.ToString())
                        {
                            string fileTime = fileName.Substring(index - 5, 4);
                            Dts.Events.FireInformation(0, "filetime ", fileTime, "", 0, ref False);
                            int fileTimeNum = Int32.Parse(fileTime);
                            Dts.Events.FireInformation(0, "savedTime ", time.ToString(), "", 0, ref 
False);
```

Find the most recent file created

```
                            if (fileTimeNum > time)
                            {
```

Save the file path of the most recent file to be FTP'd  in a later process

```
                                time = fileTimeNum;
                                fileName = ftpFilePath + fileName;
                                Dts.Events.FireInformation(0, "Most Recent ", fileName, "", 0, ref 
False);
                                Dts.Variables["User::v_File_Exists"].Value = true;
                                Dts.Variables["User::v_Remote_Path"].Value = fileName;
                            }
                        }

                }
            }

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Dts.Variables["User::v_File_Exists"].Value = false;
            Dts.Variables["User::v_Remote_Path"].Value = "";
                Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
            return;
        }

        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
```

Once the file correct file is found or not I do not want to read any sub directories

ADDED code as work around

```
                    string subFolder = fileName.Substring(0, 4);
                    //Dts.Events.FireInformation(0, "ISsubfolder ", subFolder, "", 0, ref False);
                    //Dts.Events.FireInformation(0, "Valid File ", fileName, "", 0, ref False);
                    // Prevent the process from reading the replacement files from the backup folder
                    if (subFolder != "bkup")
```

Comment: Are you asking how to break out of the while loop? If so, break will do that.

Comment: This process is reading the root level and all the sub directories.  I only want to see the file name listed at the root level then stop.  If the file is found at a sub folder level it will send back a false positive.